# Combinatorics R

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics

I have a problem I think best can be solved using cominatorics.

Lets say you have values 4 values (2,5,6,7). I would like to get all vectors where I pick out 3 of them, that is I would like a matrix with (2,5,6),(2,5,7),(5,6,7). I would like to do this with a general vector. How do I do it?

Comment: I think you missed (2, 6, 7).  If that was intentionally left out then you'll need to explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- c(2, 5, 6, 7)
combn(x, 3)
```

gives

```
> combn(x, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    5
[2,]    5    5    6    6
[3,]    6    7    7    7
```

Comment: Thank you!, I see that I even forgot one of the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a package [iterpc](http://rtalks.net/iterpc/) which is able to solve most of the combination/permutation related problems.

```
library(iterpc)
x <- c(2, 5, 6, 7)
# combinations
getall(iterpc(4, 3, label=x))
# combinations with replacement
getall(iterpc(4, 3, replace=TRUE, label=x))
# permutations
getall(iterpc(4, 3, label=x, ordered=TRUE))
```